# ASUS has a worldwide guarantee on Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: nexus-7

Today my nexus 7 2013 tablet become a brick without any previous sign.

I imported it from USA, but I live in Europe, so I could not send it back to the USA to a repair. Anybody know that ASUS has a worldwide guarantee on Nexus 7 2013? Where I can find it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2392394) on XDA Developers, user *swisstourist* claims that there is an international warranty from ASUS.

You can view the 2013 Nexus 7's warranty policy and warranty claim procedure on [ASUSTeK's website](http://support.asus.com/Warranty.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207%20%282013%29&p=28&s=2).

Hopefully these links may be of help.